# nil value while fetching structs satisfying an interface from map of string keys and struct values

Tags: go

```
type Animal interface {
    Eat()
    Move()
    Speak()
}

type Cow struct {
    food       string
    locomotion string
    noise      string
}

 func (c Cow) Eat(){
 ...
 }
// other functions of Animal for Cow

type Bird struct {
    food       string
    locomotion string
    noise      string
}

// functions of Animal for bird

type Snake struct {
    food       string
    locomotion string
    noise      string
}

// functions of Animal for Snake
```

I create instances of these structs based on user input and save them to a map

```
createdMsg := "Created it!"
animalMap := make(map[string]Animal)
// read whitespace separated user input into a String split it by space and save to array inputs
cow := Cow{"grass", "walk", "moo"}
animalMap[inputs[1]] = cow
```

here `inputs[1]` is the key(`scary`) against which I saved a struct `{mice slither hsss}`; when I enter the commands I can see a map with string keys and value structs

```
enter command(newanimal or query, name, action separated by spaces) >newanimal scary snake
Created it!
map[scary:{mice slither hsss}]
enter command(newanimal or query, name, action separated by spaces) >newanimal fatty cow
Created it!
map[fatty:{grass walk moo} scary:{mice slither hsss}]
```

But when I fetch objects `animalName := animalMap[inputs[1]]` and call `println` or `reflect.ValueOf(&animalName)` on them I get `nil`

I've also tried

```
var animalName Animal
animalName = animalMap[inputs[1]]
```

Comment: If you put a value for a key in a map and you can't retrieve it using the same key, it's most likely not the same key. Try printing the string key using `"%q"` to see "invisible" characters (such as newlines). Also provide a [mcve], preferably with a Go Playground link.

Comment: `reflect.ValueOf(&animalName)` should be `reflect.ValueOf(animalName)`. But there is not `animalName  is nil` issue.